# Using gprof with pthreads

Tags: multithreading, profiling, pthreads, gprof

Can gprof be used to profile a multi-threaded program that uses pthreads? That is, will its output include the time used in all the threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with the help of a workaround described [here](http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [**pstack**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834103/ways-to-corner-a-stickiness-bug/1834447#1834447)? It works fine with multiple threads, and it is good for finding performance problems by the stackshot method.
[**gprof**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343) is what it is, but chances are you can do better.