# Ubuntu, how to find hotspot of program with heavy kernel work? It seems function at kernel.kallsyms doesn't mark as user space function's children

Tags: c++, profiling, perf, gprof

Multi-thread program with heavy kernel work( lock unlock), try to find the hot spot at my code use profiling tools.

I wrote a minimum reproducible program. Compile it. Use profiling tool such as perf , gprof with callstack record. None of then can report the hot spot at my code, but report function at kernel or libstdc++.so.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::mutex mtx;
long long_val = 0;

void do_something(long &val)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    for(int j=0; j<1000; ++j)
        val++;
}


void thread_func()
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000000L; ++i)
    {
        do_something(long_val);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> threads;
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(thread_func))));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        threads[i]->join();
    }
    threads.clear();
    std::cout << long_val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As we can se, `do_something()` is my program's hot spot. because too much of unique_lock cost lots of kernel work, and 1000 times of inc operate at the function.

**I want profiling tool tell me that, It is do_something() make a lot of lock, cause lots of kernel work. but from `perf`, I only can found it is lock slow down my code, but where made these lock operates at my code? it is not clear.**

Compile:

`g++ -o a.out -O3 -std=c++11 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -pg main.cpp`

Run program`./a.out`, htop report kernel taken half of CPU resource.

Perf record:

`perf record -g ./a.out`

Perf report:

```
      Children      Self  Command  Shared Object        Symbol
    -   98.64%     0.00%  a.out    libstdc++.so.6.0.21  [.] 0x00000000000b8c80
       - 0xb8c80
          + 41.80% __lll_unlock_wake
          + 35.39% __lll_lock_wait
        12.77% pthread_mutex_lock
        7.69% pthread_mutex_unlock
        0.70% _Z11thread_funcv
    -   49.21%     0.88%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
       + 48.33% entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
         0.88% 0xb8c80
    -   47.64%     1.06%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] do_syscall_64
       + 46.59% do_syscall_64
       + 1.06% 0xb8c80
    -   47.18%     1.44%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] sys_futex
       + 45.74% sys_futex
       + 1.44% 0xb8c80
    -   45.55%     1.65%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] do_futex
       + 43.90% do_futex
       + 1.65% 0xb8c80
    -   41.80%     1.30%  a.out    libpthread-2.23.so   [.] __lll_unlock_wake
       + 40.50% __lll_unlock_wake
       + 1.30% 0xb8c80
    -   35.39%     4.53%  a.out    libpthread-2.23.so   [.] __lll_lock_wait
       + 30.86% __lll_lock_wait
       + 4.53% 0xb8c80
    -   20.51%     5.40%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] futex_wake
       + 15.11% futex_wake
       + 5.40% 0xb8c80
    -   19.41%     0.88%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] futex_wait
       + 18.53% futex_wait
       + 0.88% 0xb8c80
    -   16.92%     6.25%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] _raw_spin_lock
       + 10.67% _raw_spin_lock
       + 6.25% 0xb8c80
    -   12.77%    12.73%  a.out    libpthread-2.23.so   [.] pthread_mutex_lock
         12.73% 0xb8c80
        pthread_mutex_lock
    +   11.80%     5.41%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] futex_wait_setup
    +   11.05%    11.05%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] syscall_return_via_sysret
    +   10.68%    10.67%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath
    +    7.69%     7.65%  a.out    libpthread-2.23.so   [.] pthread_mutex_unlock
    +    7.36%     0.11%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] wake_up_q
    +    7.17%     1.27%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] try_to_wake_up
    +    4.42%     0.23%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] futex_wait_queue_me
    +    4.17%     0.08%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] schedule
    +    3.84%     0.75%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] __schedule
    +    2.70%     0.01%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] ttwu_do_activate
    +    2.49%     2.48%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] get_futex_value_locked
    +    2.38%     0.11%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] activate_task
    +    2.26%     0.15%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] enqueue_task_fair
    +    1.88%     1.88%  a.out    [unknown]            [k] 0xfffffe000000601b
    +    1.84%     0.15%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] __task_rq_lock
    +    1.78%     1.78%  a.out    [unknown]            [k] 0xfffffe000005e01b
    +    1.77%     1.77%  a.out    [unknown]            [k] 0xfffffe000003201b
    +    1.67%     0.02%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] deactivate_task
    +    1.66%     1.66%  a.out    [unknown]            [k] 0xfffffe000008a01b
```

**How can I use a profiling tool, to figure out this type hot spot at my really program. I don't want use "binary chop comment" to solve it every time. Thanks!**

Comment: Have you tried a GUI on top of perf? Or VTune?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I profiling program at remote server without X via ssh. We have no VTune license, havn't tryed it.

Comment: Try using perf with [FlameGraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) (yeah, it is exceptionally ugly perl gibberish, however it does produce nice visualizations).

Comment: @VTT but it seems that perf doesn't make kernel function call as userspace function's children. I tryed `hotspot` gui, doesn't help.

Comment: Doesn't their [example](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpu-bash-flamegraph.svg) show exactly this - stacks with kernel function calls from userspace functions?

Comment: It seems someone has found the solution to make gprof work with multithreaded applications: http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html

Comment: This solution is already given on so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/922478/5632316

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using gprof with pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922475/using-gprof-with-pthreads)

Comment: @Oliv hook pthread function is not acceptable. And gprof is not my key point, but how to make `perf report` mark kernel function as userspace function's children is.

Comment: @VTT Thanks, I will have a try.

Comment: @BinZhou I have been able to get the information you need. You must change perf command line `perf record --call-graph dwarf ./a.out` (you may need to pass -g at the compiler or not to get debug info in the object file) then `perf report --call-graph --stdio -G`.

Comment: @BinZhou any luck ?

Answer (score 1):

`perf` uses frame pointer unwinding by default, which is fast, but unreliable. Even if your application does not omit frame pointers, the libraries may.

Alternatively you can use `--call-graph` with either `dwarf` or `lbr`.

`dwarf` records stack chunks during sampling that are later evaluated. It can give more details, but creates huge traces and may have more perturbation.

`lbr` requires hardware support available at newer Intel processors.

It will show something like this:

```
99.25%     2.61%  a.out    a.out                [.] thread_func
        |          
        |--97.67%--thread_func
        |          |          
        |          |--45.33%--pthread_mutex_lock@plt
        |          |          
        |          |--28.65%--pthread_mutex_unlock@plt
        |          |          
        |          |--18.88%--__pthread_mutex_lock
        |          |          __lll_lock_wait
        |          |          
        |           --4.75%--__pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt
        |                     __lll_unlock_wake
        |          
         --0.72%--__pthread_mutex_lock
```

Comment: `g++ -o a.out -O3 -std=c++11 -pthread -g main.cpp`  `perf record --call-graph lbr ./a.out`  `perf report` top3 is `entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe`%48.81 `do_syscall_64`%47.25 `sys_futex`%47.01

Comment: But if compile with `g++ -o a.out -O2 -std=c++11 -pthread -g main.cpp`, then top3 of `Children` is `_Z11thread_funcv`%79.18 `pthread_mutex_unlock`%57.51 `entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe`%49.56. Could you please help me understand why this happen.

Comment: result of `uname -a`: Linux PC 4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 7 13:31:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`